# How to Reset Circular Progress Button Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I just want to know that how to reset circular progress button once it completes loading?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on which button or library you are using. Look in the user guide for a way to setState or setProgress or something like that.

For example, in this library https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button/wiki/User-Guide in the past, there's a method called CircularProgressButton.setProgress(100).